# HTTPS NGINX configuration for redirecting traffic

Tags: nginx, https

I´ve achieved to redirect all the HTTP traffic to HTTPS. Here is the configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Now I want to redirect https://192.168.../ (IP) to the DNS domain name. How can I do it?

Thank you,

Comment: Have `server_name <ip>` do the redirect to `https://hardcodedhostname$request_uri`.

Comment: I´ve done it, but id doesn´t redirect https:IP to https:DNS.  
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name 192.168...;
        return 301 https://hardcodedhostname$request_uri;
}

Comment: It does if it listens on port 443. But it's not going to make the invalid certificate error go away.

Comment: how can I delete the invalid certificate error? Because when I enter to HTTPS with the domain name i didn´t get it.

Comment: You can avoid the error by not using the URI with the IP address anywhere.